# How map work on Options in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pure-function

I have this two functions

```
  def pattern(s: String): Option[Pattern] =
try {
  Some(Pattern.compile(s))
} catch {
  case e: PatternSyntaxException => None
}
```

and

```
  def mkMatcher(pat: String): Option[String => Boolean] =
     pattern(pat) map (p => (s: String) => p.matcher(s).matches)
```

Map is the higher-order function that applies a given function to each element of a list.

Now I am not getting that how map is working here as per above statement.

Comment: "Map is the higher-order function that applies a given function to each element of a list" is an overly specific statement. Lots of things make sense to map.

Comment: What do you mean by Lots of things make sense to map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Map is the higher-order function that applies a given function to each element of a list.

This is an uncommonly restrictive definition of map.

At any rate, it works because it was defined by someone who did not hold to that.

For example, that someone wrote something akin to

```
sealed trait Option[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
    case Some(value) => Some(f(value))
    case None => None
  }
}
```

as part of the standard library. This makes map applicable to `Option[A]`

It was defined because it makes sense to map many kinds of data structures not just lists.
Mapping is a transformation applied to the elements held by the data structure.

It applies a function to each element.

`Option[A]` can be thought of as a trivial sequence. It either has zero or one elements. To map it means to apply the function on its element if it has one.

Now it may not make much sense to use this facility all of the time, but there are cases where it is useful.

For example, it is one of a few distinct methods that, when present enable enable *For Expressions* to operate on a type. `Option[A]` can be used in for expressions which can be convenient.

For example

```
val option: Option[Int] = Some(2)

val squared: Option[Int] = for {
  n <- option
  if n % 2 == 0
} yield n * n
```

Interestingly, this implies that *filter* is also defined on `Option[A]`.

If you just have a simple value it may well be clearer to use a less general construct.

Comment: That means in my case `pattern(pat)` is an trivial sequence and `(p => (s: String) => p.matcher(s).matches)` is a function which is map is mapping onto it? And `pattern(pat)` is a list which can be either contain one element or no element?

Comment: Yes. There are reasons to want to map options but in that case, I would use `match` or `if` because it would be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Map is working the same way that it does with other collections types like List and Vector. It applies your function to the contents of the  collection, potentially changing the type but keeping the collection type the same.

In many cases you can treat an Option just like a collection with either 0 or 1 elements. You can do a lot of the same operations on Option that you can on other collections.

You can modify the value

```
var opt = Option(1)

opt.map(_ + 3)
opt.map(_ * math.Pi)
opt.filter(_ == 1)
opt.collect({case i if i > 0 => i.toString })

opt.foreach(println)
```

and you can test the value

```
opt.contains(3)
opt.forall(_ > 0)
opt.exists(_ > 0)
opt.isEmpty
```

Using these methods you rarely need to use a match statement to unpick an Option.